# Precedence and parentheses In Join. How can I write below SQL query in objection ORM?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, knex.js

I have the following SQL query:

```
select p.id, p.slug, p.post_author, b.id, b.is_deleted  from posts p 
left join blocks b 
on 
    ((b.blocked_id = p.post_author and blocker_id = <user id>)
    or 
    (b.blocked_id = <user_id> and b.blocker_id = p.post_author))
    and b.is_deleted = false
where b.id is null
order by posted_at  desc limit 20
```

and need a corresponding objection orm statement, and I'm not sure how to bring in those bracket precedence. Below is what I have as a modifier so far:

```
getUnblockedUsersPosts: (builder) => {
            builder.leftJoin('blocks as b', function(){
              this.on('b.blocked_id', '=', 'posts.post_author')
              .andOn('b.blocker_id', '=', parseInt(user.id))
              .orOn('b.blocked_id', '=', parseInt(user.id))
              .andOn('b.blocker_id', '=', 'posts.post_author')
              .andOn('b.is_deleted', knex.raw('false'))
            }).where('b.id', 'is', null)      
          },
```

Comment: ORM isn't for you if you're thinking in terms of SQL.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with "objection ORM" but with most ORM systems, you would define the link between models (belongsTo, hasMany, etc), how the link matches, and reference them in your builder. However, your join is rather complicated and as such it isn't an easy thing to define that link. Perhaps someone more versed with "objection ORM" can help you convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So above query was solved by the below code,
reference: https://knexjs.org/#Builder-join

```
getUnblockedUsersPosts: (builder) => {
            builder.leftJoin('blocks as b', function(){
              this.on(function(){
                this.on(function(){
                  this.on('b.blocked_id', '=', 'posts.post_author')
                  .andOn('b.blocker_id', '=', parseInt(user.id))
                })
                this.orOn(function(){
                  this.on('b.blocker_id', '=', 'posts.post_author')
                  .andOn('b.blocked_id', '=', parseInt(user.id))
                })
              })
              this.andOn('b.is_deleted', knex.raw('false'))
            }).where('b.id', 'is', null)      
          }
```